# How can I get springboot transaction'data in jooq query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jooq

So I have a problem in jooq about getting data in spring-boot transaction.
I use a transaction to save the base data, and then I want to use jooq to get these data. But I found that what I fetched is null.

```java
    String sql = dslContext.select().from(Tables.SALES_INVENTORY).getSQL();
    System.out.println(sql);
    Result<Record> fetch1 = dslContext.select().from(Tables.SALES_INVENTORY).fetch();
    System.out.println(fetch1);
    String groupbySql =
        dslContext
            .select(Tables.SALES_INVENTORY.ITEM_ID, sum(Tables.SALES_INVENTORY.ON_HAND_QTY))
            .from(Tables.SALES_INVENTORY)
            .groupBy(Tables.SALES_INVENTORY.ITEM_ID)
            .getSQL();
    System.out.println(groupbySql);
    Result<Record2<UUID, BigDecimal>> fetch =
        dslContext
            .select(Tables.SALES_INVENTORY.ITEM_ID, sum(Tables.SALES_INVENTORY.ON_HAND_QTY))
            .from(Tables.SALES_INVENTORY)
            .groupBy(Tables.SALES_INVENTORY.ITEM_ID)
            .fetch();
    System.out.println(fetch);

    List<SalesInventoryEntity> all = salesInventoryRepository.findAll();
    all.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Jooq's SQL is correct, but can't find and data return as if I use JPA @Transactional to do my test method. And I use jpa-repository to get data, it found the right data.

So my main problem is how can I get the right data in JPA transactional?

---

Here is what I used to init the base data. It's a test method, and its class is @Transactional, so this means that the method is also @Transactional?

```java
 public void initSalesInventories() {

    List<SalesInventoryEntity> salesInventories = Lists.newArrayList();

    ItemEntity itemEntity = itemRepository.findById(itemId1).get();

    int i = 0;
    for (StockLocationEntity stockLocationEntity : stockLocationEntities) {

      SalesInventoryEntity salesInventoryEntity = new SalesInventoryEntity();
      salesInventoryEntity.setStockLocation(stockLocationEntity);
      salesInventoryEntity.setSalesOrganization(usSalesOrgEntity);
      salesInventoryEntity.setItem(itemEntity);
      salesInventoryEntity.setItemClass(ItemClass.SALEABLE);
      salesInventoryEntity.setOnHandQty(100);
      salesInventoryEntity.setReservedQty(0);
      salesInventoryEntity.setAvailableQty(100);
      salesInventoryEntity.setLeadTime(5);
      DocumentType[] values = DocumentType.values();
      salesInventoryEntity.setDocType(values[i % 7]);
      String code = "TO-201906112010000" + i;
      i++;
      salesInventoryEntity.setDocCode(code);
      salesInventories.add(salesInventoryEntity);
    }

    salesInventoryRepository.saveAll(salesInventories);
  }
```

After init my base data, I used jooq to read the data, and find nothing. I  don't know whether jooq can't read other transaction's data or jooq just read the actual data from the database. If you know something about it please give me some advices.

Comment: I think it happened because jooq's query is not the same transaction with jpa repositroy even they in the same method, so how can I make them use the same transaction so that jooq's query can read jpa's uncommited data

Comment: @Lukas Eder could you help me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it indeed looks like there are separate transactions being used. Can you please also show how you have created your `DSLContext`? Since you are using Spring Boot the simplest way would be to add a dependency to the `spring-boot-starter-jooq` starter module. See also this article for some more details: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-support-for-jooq

Comment: yeah, I'm using spring-boot-starter-jooq starter module. I use @Autowired to create my DSLContext, and I think it's using JooqAutoConfiguration to create DSLContext Bean.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a reproducable example (possibly using the [jOOQ MCVE template](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve)? Otherwise it will be very hard to tell what the problem is here.

Comment: Hi, I edit my problem just now, cloud you have a minute to take a look? Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Possibly Hibernate (I assume that is what you use) has all the data still buffered. Does it work if you add a call to `salesInventoryRepository.flush()` after the `saveAll()` call?

Comment: I can try that. But the main problem is that as if I use repository to save data in another transaction the jooq query can't read the uncommitted data. I think I need a static method to allow jooq query to access hibernate's buffered data.

Comment: @knutwannheden hi man, I use flush to test, it's succeed. But I do want to know does the jooq query can read another transaction's data, or it just because my config isn't right. Please let me know, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Your question regarding the transactions isn't really specific to jOOQ. This depends on what transaction isolation level you are using in your database session. Typically READ_COMMITTED is the default and it will require you to commit the transaction before the changes can be seen from any other transaction.

Comment: I tried to change the transactional isolation level to READ_UNCOMMITTED, but it didn't work out as I expected.

Comment: I am a bit confused, whether you have two separate transactions or not and which it is you want. Can you clarify this? The fact that the flush helped, indicates to me that there is in fact just a single transaction and in that case I don't see any way you can do without the flush, as jOOQ can't access Hibernate's internal buffers. But I also don't see any problem with a flush, as it shouldn't commit the transaction.

Comment: If they are in the same transaction, does jooq have ability to access Hibernate's internal buffers? Or it's just because my own jooq config is error. I'm using JooqAutoConfiguration to load my DSLContext.

Comment: No, jOOQ cannot access Hibernate internal buffers and I don't see how this would make sense either. Using flush() is the answer for your problem, when running in the same transaction.

Comment: OK, that's all I need. Really thankful.